# How to block search engines from finding sub.domains?

Tags: php, .htaccess, search, web-crawler

I want to block search engines like Google and Yahoo from crawling user sub.domains like user.example.com, how can i do it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 5):

Use [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt) file in your web server.

So, in your subdomain put a robots.txt file that looks like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Comment: Do i have to add the sub domain name in the file or just what you have put up here.  Can i also use disallow: all  Thanks!

Comment: @AAA: Nope, all you need is the above... Disallow all is basically `Disallow: /` since it disallows robots to visit any page from the root directory and down (all pages).

Comment: Facebook has done it in a very different way:                       http://facebook.com/robots.txt    why have they specified?

Answer (score 0):

All sites have something specifically specified because that's what they don't want crawled by search engines...